# NetBeans Platform (RCP) and "Package as Installers" with serial number

Tags: installation, rcp, netbeans-platform

This is my first time using the NetBeans Platform (RCP) for an application. I would like to package the application as .exe installer, and now I know how to do that. What I do not know, is it possible to customize this NetBeans RCP installer to prompt the user for a serial number? Please, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The only way presently (and that I know of) to do this is to edit the installer's source. The code that is used to create an application's installer is shared between all NBP projects and as such it is probably not a good idea to do this. Another option for you is to create a "setup" wizard that runs the first time the application runs and gets the serial number then. For reference, the installer code on a Windows 7 machine is located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\harness\nbi"

Comment: Thank you Jonathan once again, your answers are perfectly what I am looking for.

Comment: By the way Jonathan, do you know of any good Java tutorials teaching how to generate serial numbers and validate them, also tutorials for creating Wizards? Thank you so much again

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer and expanded on it a bit. I'm afraid I can't recommend any tutorials on serial number generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way presently (and that I know of) to do this is to edit the installer's source. The code that is used to create an application's installer is shared between all NBP projects and as such it is probably not a good idea to do this. For reference, the installer code on a Windows 7 machine is located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.1\harness\nbi".

Another option for you is to create a "setup" wizard that runs the first time the application runs and gets the serial number then. This is also considered good practice although I have seen applications that ask for a serial number on installation. In general your installer should only be concerned with installing; activating a product should be handled in a setup process.

**Edit:** The NetBeans Platform has a built in Wizard located in the Dialog API. Of course, The best resource for learning about the NetBeans Platform is the http://platform.netbeans.org site. If you are using 7.1 then [this is the tutorial you want](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html).